# Extra Padding on my site using ProfitBuilder WP

Tags: html, wordpress, css, padding

I am currently copying this site: http://www.onlinemeetingnow.com/register/?id=q6wpivs95c& here: http://beaminggeek.com/profitbuilder/test-2/

and using a WP tool called ProfitBuilder: http://wpprofitbuilder.com/

I have three issues here in particular.
1. I put margin-top: 20px; on my  tag (to push it on the center) on the image below however when I do it adds up a margin on the both top and below:

[image]

[image]

Here's my code on that:

```
<h2 style="text-align: center; font-size: 40px; font-weight: bold;"><span style="color: #ffffff; ">The 4-Step Strategy We Used to Build a</span><br /> <span style="color: #ffffff;"> 7-Figure Coaching Business...</span><br /> <span style="color: #ffffff; font-size: 25px; "> (while ignoring ALL the conventional wisdom!)</span></h2><p style="text-align: center;"><a style="font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed'; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffd800',endColorstr='#f7d100'); background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top,#ffd800 5%,#f7d100 100%); background-color: #ffd800; display: block; margin: 0 auto; position: relative; min-height: 33px; width: 280px; text-decoration: none; font-weight: bold; font-size: 30px; color: #fdffff; cursor: pointer; border-radius: 3px; -webkit-border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; border: none; padding: 17px 10px; text-align: center; z-index: 2; margin-top: 12px;" href="#">Claim My Spot Now >></a></p>
```

I also have some issues with this two section here as there are spaces all around:

[image]

Any idea what to move to make it look perfect using inline-CSS? YOu can use Chrome inspector tool to check this.

NOTE: The Profit Builder Tool is a tool that doesnt go with custom css panel with it meaning everything is just plain inline CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `padding-bottom` set for your Claim Your Spot Now button. So when you put a `margin-top` value on top of your `h2` it pushes your `p` down as well and the `padding-bottom` of the `p` pushes down the following section

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work

```
body {
    margin: -1px 0 0 0
}

h2 {
    margin: 25px 0 0 0;
}

.pbuilder_column {
    margin: 0 0 -24px 0
}
```